# Unable to convert wchar_t to std::wstring

Tags: c++, std, wchar-t, wstring

I have the following piece of simple code in the `main()` function.

Unfortunately, I cannot get `main()` to `wcout` the converted `wchar_t` array. Why is this so?

```
int main(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
    std::wcout << "first argument: " << std::wstring(argv[1])
}
```

this just prints

> first argument:

Comment: The signature for `main` should be `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`  Looks like you are using a MSVC extension - live - https://godbolt.org/z/bh6o45  Standard definition of `main` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

Comment: How many arguments are you giving to the program when you start it?

Comment: You probably want [`wmain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/using-wmain?view=msvc-160) for `wchar_t argv`, not `main`.

Comment: I am using MSVC 2019 and frankly am a novice at C++ programming. The standard definition that is generated for a console application is main(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])

Comment: I am giving 3 arguments to my program, input file, output file and compression ratio (an integer)

Comment: @rustyx yes you seem to be right, changing main to wmain works.